# iOS API to manage push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

This is a long shot, but are there any public (or private) APIs that allow us to read existing push notifications on an iOS device?  For example, can an app running in the background poll the system every X seconds to determine if the device has received a push notification from the Stack Exchange app and get its contents?

The thought here is there are some services (such as the Ring Video Doorbell) that do not yet have public REST APIs.  But when there is motion detected on the Ring camera, it sends a push notification.  Similar to the popular IFTTT service, this app would poll for that notification on the device and then do something based on criteria set by the user.

I imagine there has to at least be a private API since Apple shows the device's recent notifications in the Notification Center.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if it was possible to use an unsupported API that violated app security, the contents of the push notification are encrypted and you may not be able to read the contents.

However, Apple's Developer site has information on relaying and interacting with other app's push notifications over bluetooth for a bluetooth ANCS.

> "The purpose of the Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) is to
>   give Bluetooth accessories (that connect to iOS devices through a
>   Bluetooth low-energy link) a simple and convenient way to access many
>   kinds of notifications that are generated on iOS devices."

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH2-SW1

This may not be applicable to you, but it is Apple's approved method for interacting with, and relaying push notifications from other apps to bluetooth devices.

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far.  You have at least provided a possible alternative instead of a simple "No, not possible". There is always a way to do most things.  This app will never be published to the store anyway.

Comment: While this is one interpretation, I've answered another of a possible solution, along with the core reason as to why you can't read another app's pure pushes (it's not because their just encrypted, privacy wise Apple wants each app to be in a sandbox with user granted external privileges the system controls). @TheValyreanGroup I hope that my answer is also helpful

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup: Don't forget to award the bounty by clicking the bit under the green tick on the left.

Answer (score 9):

No, that's not possible. It seems that it will be a privacy issue if other apps will read other apps push notifications content.

Comment: Not sure I understand why someone down-voted this.  Don't shoot the messenger if you don't like the answer, but that's the answer.  Counteracted with an up-vote.

Comment: This seems like a reasonably downvoted answer since it does not draw from any sources, which is what the bounty is asking for.

Comment: @BHendricks there is no such source. If it was, I would definitely provide a link to it.

Comment: That's precisely what I have in my answer. The reason you understand that other apps can't access your content is because of Apple's sandbox, which whether youre aware of it or not is the core mechanism you could've sourced :) so @Shmidt that's where my first comment is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

Apple would never give such API private/Public, this will violate apps security.You can only read your apps push notifications.

if you use private API , there is good chance that your app will be rejected when you submit to app store.

some possible solutions to your app.

1) Figure out is there any way your app gets that push notification.

2) Or you have to use Inter-App Communication.

Comment: Under the interpretation of purely sniffing push notis, this is definitely fairly accurate (although unsourced). There are other ways to get device-level notifications though that aren't strictly "push notifications" but to your app could be perceived as a similar form of update. All of which are controlled by the system with system-standard permission dialogs that your users are used to.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this question to be asking specifically in the lens of a IFTTT device that could already read/write data to a "standard" IFTTT app, and you're wondering how that's done. To me, that's the question, and not asking about a hacky private API push notification system.

With that in mind, the solution is generally referred to as `HomeKit` from what I know. It's one of Apple's "Kits", with general docs found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HomeKitDeveloperGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

What I think you're looking to do is more along the lines of database observation, where you're maybe looking to build some aggregator app of this data set stored on the device (which Apple has a standard method of asking users for permissions, and is fully allowed on the system just like Camera/Health/Photo permissions, etc).

Observing HomeKit database changes is found at a developer doc linked from the first, but found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HomeKitDeveloperGuide/RespondingtoHomeKitDatabaseChanges/RespondingtoHomeKitDatabaseChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015050-CH5-SW2)

I haven't used this before myself, but from the docs, I can see there are methods for observation using regular old iOS KVO:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateHomes:) name:@"UpdateHomesNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updatePrimaryHome:) name:@"UpdatePrimaryHomeNotification"  object:nil];`

There's a lot more info there, and I'm sure StackOverflow itself (and old WWDC videos of course) have lots of info on HomeKit.
I hope this was the intended interpretation the question-asker meant. 
Similarly, though, each of the supported channels for events (HealthKit, MapKit, etc) can send you "push notification" type updates about what your user is doing with built-in APIs.

If you're attempting to simply read from other application's push payloads, then the other answers are correct and that is not possible on a pure privacy basis that Apple sandboxes your application: [Apple Sandbox Docs Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

Comment: It's good that you provided link to sandbox docs. By thee way, ```NSNotificationCenter``` is not KVO.

Comment: I meant KVO as more of the general paradigm being used, but you're right that the notification Center example I provided is not KVO, although it definitely follows a very similar pattern in terms of generic mechanisms (the Center still has observation over events, they're just implemented in different ways compared to pure KVO). Regardless, the core idea stays the same, and would also apply to the delegation pattern several Kits I mention/hint about use for notification & updates the original question seems to be interested in. Again, my interpretation seems quite different than most on this 1