# Can an iOS or Android app interact with another apps interactive push notifications?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I'm looking to make an app for myself that will sleep until a push notification from another specific app comes through and then automatically accepts or declines the interactive push notification. Is it even possible to have an app that reacts to other apps push notifications? If it could react, then could it then interact with the notification?

I know that apps cant directly interact with the interfaces of others, but since this would be using push notifications I was hoping there would be something I could do. I cant find anything on this anywhere else or at least I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about IOS but in Android we could use to listen Broadcast to listen Broadscasts by system and other apps. But i think there has been some restrictions recently with Broadcast due to battery optimisation. Of-course you can achieve this with another app only if you know what broadcast they're triggering so you need to have some partnership with these other apps.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS:**

I fairly doubt that it is possible on iOS with a straightforward API, but take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523429/768567

---

**Android:**

For Android you could implement a `NotificationListenerService`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

There is a repository on Github with some example code:
https://github.com/Chagall/notification-listener-service-example